# Wpf Drag&Drop and send back

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

i am getting stuck to apply a feature in my project with Drag&Drop developing in WPF/C#, i can post you an example of code of what i want to do as follow :

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="box1" Grid.Row="0" >
            <Grid Name="grid1" Background="Aqua" Margin="15"></Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="box2" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid Name="grid2" Background="blue" Margin="15"></Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="box3" Grid.Row="2" >
            <Grid Name="grid3" Background="green" Margin="15"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

each Grid(box) contains another Grid my simple purpose is to drag the "grid1" to the "box2" then automatically the "grid2" go to the "box1" and this rule is applied every time i want drag&drop ; the Grid "box" is always not movable .
From many days i check out many project and library online as GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop,Blacklight.ShowCase.WPF and else but don't cover my request because in each grid there are many controls binding data(in the real project should be 30 grid more all controls ) then an ItemControl don't cover my purpose.
I am easy to do a simple Drag&Drop but in this case is more complicated for me then i ask you kindly if you have any suggestion or idea to work out this case.

I give in anticipate my apologies if my question result weird as i have not much experience in WPF.

Thank you in anticipate

Comment: How do you add the `grid1` to `container2`? add the c# code in the question.

Comment: There's a Drop event for every element instate the swap there

Comment: @Shaharyar Yes i added the code but it is allow to drag drop but not allow to add the grid1 in the container2.Thank you for your feedback !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all you are trying to do is to swap grid elements between two boxes. In order to do that, you need to add `Drop` event to boxes, and `MouseMove` event to grids, like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="box1" Grid.Row="0" AllowDrop="True" Drop="box_Drop" >
        <Grid Name="grid1" Background="Aqua" Margin="15" MouseMove="grid_MouseMove">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="box2" Grid.Row="1" AllowDrop="True" Drop="box_Drop">
        <Grid Name="grid2" Background="blue" Margin="15" MouseMove="grid_MouseMove">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="box3" Grid.Row="2" AllowDrop="True" Drop="box_Drop">
        <Grid Name="grid3" Background="green" Margin="15" MouseMove="grid_MouseMove">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Next, add code to handle those events.

For `MouseMove`:

```
/// <summary>
/// MouseMove event handler
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the grid that is the source of drag
    Grid selectedGrid = sender as Grid;

    if (selectedGrid != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        // Add that grid as drag source and data
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(selectedGrid, selectedGrid, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

And for `Drop`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Drop event handler
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void box_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the selected box in which the object is being dropped
    Grid selectedBox = sender as Grid;

    if (selectedBox != null)
    {
        // Get that data that is being dropped - in this case, the grid from other box
        Grid droppedGrid = (Grid)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Grid));

        // We need to remove the dragged grid from it's source box in order to be able to add it to selected box
        Grid sourceBox = (Grid)droppedGrid.Parent;
        // Remove the dropped grid from source box
        sourceBox.Children.Remove(droppedGrid);

        // We need to remove the other grid from the selected box in order to be able to move it to source box
        // Get existing child element, the box has only one child - the grid that we need
        Grid existingChild = (Grid)selectedBox.Children[0];
        // Remove existing child grid from selected box
        selectedBox.Children.Remove(existingChild);

        // Finally, move grids to new boxes
        // Move existing child grid to source box
        sourceBox.Children.Add(existingChild);
        // Move the dropped grid to selected box
        selectedBox.Children.Add(droppedGrid);          
    }
}
```

Now you should be able do drag and swap grids between two boxes.

Comment: Dear friend thank yo so much for your kind support,it works very well.Wish you A Happy New year!!! @noxbyte

Comment: Glad I could help, and I wish you a Happy New Year too! @JayJay